# SVN svnsync all repo project

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn, svnsync

I have two [VisualSVNServer](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/): master (http://example.com/svn) and a mirror (backup)

In each server have the same repository structure with 100 project (20 GB):

```
D:\Repositories
               \MyProject1
               \MyProject2
               \MyProjectN
```

at the moment I sync the mirror server manually for each single project, eg:

```
svnsync synchronize http://127.0.0.1/svn/MyProject1 http://example.com/svn/MyProject1

svnsync synchronize http://127.0.0.1/svn/MyProject2 http://example.com/svn/MyProject2

svnsync synchronize http://127.0.0.1/svn/MyProjectN http://example.com/svn/MyProjectN
```

it is possible syncronyze all project in the mirror with one command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `http://127.0.0.1/svn/` is a *repository*, you can use `svnsync synchronize http://127.0.0.1/svn/MyProject1 http://example.com/svn`.

However, I suspect that this is not the case, and `http://127.0.0.1/svn/` is actually a virtual directory which is a common parent for two **independent** repositories. If this is the case, you cannot do this. Subversion simply doesn't allow for it.

**Edit:** Based on your subsequent edit, you have multiple repositories being served from a common parent (root). This is the second paragraph's scenario. You cannot sync all repositories with a single `svnsync` - you must do each individually.

So, how can you tell the difference? Run `svn info http://127.0.0.1/svn/MyProject1` and `svn info http://127.0.0.1/svn/MyProject2` If both return the same value reported for `Repository Root`, then the first paragraph applies. If you get the same URL back as the Repository Root (IOW, `Repository Root` is `http://127.0.0.1/svn/MyProject1` for `MyProject1` and `http://127.0.0.1/svn/MyProject2` for `MyProject2`, then they're separate repositories.

Comment: Then the second case applies. You can't sync all at once, you will have to sync each repository individually.

Comment: I'm sad... Thanks for the help